# Can't restore flic buttons after uninstalling and reinstaling my app

Tags: ios, swift

When my app is suspended or terminated i can restore my flic buttons in `flicManagerDidRestoreState(manager: SCLFlicManager)` with `manager.knownButtons()` function.

but when i uninstall and reinstall my app i can't restore them in my app.
Any solution ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. just 'manager.knownButtons()' return nil

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore to a state because all states are gone because you've deleted the app. I'm not sure why this is a problem (there wouldn't be a user state to come back to).

Comment: Thank you for answering. this is a problem because when user reinstall the app and login he will see the flic device installed on his account but not connected

Comment: It sounds like this is slightly more complex than the standard state restoration (though I can't be certain as your question is very short on details), however, you may need to pursue an alternate method to discover installed devices on initial app launch.

Comment: i already have buttonIdentifier of my flic button stored in my backend. it can help ?

Comment: You'll have to look at the documentation.

Comment: I already read the document here is the [link](http://flic.io/partners/developers/ios-tutorial)
I didn't find a function that reconnect my flic button by buttonIdentifier